# LINQ how to pass multiple select as function parameter

Tags: c#, linq

How can I pass multiple custom select as function parameter?
Something like this:

```
Test(x=> new {x.var1, x.var5, x.var3} );
Test(x=> new {x.var1, x.var3, t=x.RetSomething()} );


void Test<myCls>(Func<myCls> sel) {
  foreach( var cols in myList.Select(sel) ) {
     //And how to know number of params and access them?
```

each var1, var-n could be differents types. How to access each one individually in the function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use object array?

```
public static void Test<T>(Func<T, object[]> sel)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(myCls))
        {
            foreach (var cols in myList.Cast<T>().Select(sel))
            {
                foreach (var col in cols)
                {
                    // do stuff on each col
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
Test((myCls x) => new object[] { x.var1, x.var2, x.var3 });
Test((myCls x) => new object[] { x.var1, x.var4 });
```

Comment: thanks, it's what I'm looking for.
It's simple and I think, faster that reflexion solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it seems to be an instance of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) but to answer your question I see next options here:

1. Pass the action into your `Test` method:

```
    void Test<myCls>(Func<myCls> sel, Action<myCls> act) {
      foreach( var cols in myList.Select(i => sel()) ) {
         act(cols)
      }
    }
```

And call the method like this:

```
Test(x=> new {x.var1, x.var5, x.var3} , x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.var1}, {x.var5}, {x.var3}"));
```

2. If you can limit number of parameter to some realistic number you can have n overloads with tuples:

```
    void Test<TFrom, T1, T2>(Func<TFrom, (T1, T2)> sel)
    {
        var myList = (new[] {default(TFrom)});
        foreach (var cols in myList.Select(t => sel(t)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{cols.Item1}, {cols.Item2}");
        }
    }

    void Test<TFrom, T1, T2, T3>(Func<TFrom, (T1, T2, T3)> sel)
    {...}

    and so on.....
```

And usage:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int I1 { get; set; }
    public string S1 { get; set; }
}

Test((MyClass x) => (x.I1, x.S1));
```

3. Dive into [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) and possibly [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/). Just to get you started :

```
   void Test<myCls>(Func<myCls> sel) {
      var props = typeof(TFrom).GetProperties();
      foreach( var cols in myList.Select(i => sel()) ) {
         foreach (var prop in props){
             Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.GetValue(cols)}");
         }
      }
    }
```

This code can be greatly improved via caching the reflection per type and maybe even compiling your inner logic via expression trees.

Comment: The solution 1, it doesn't work, it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Of course, if my code had worked, I wouldn't have asked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netcore-3.1) to access properties of anonymous objects:

```
void Test<TResult>(Func<myCls, TResult> sel) // don't forget to specify projection result
{
    var properties = typeof(TResult).GetProperties();
    // use properties.Length to get number of params

    foreach (var cols in myList.Select(sel))
    {
        foreach (var property in properties)
            Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} = {property.GetValue(cols)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!
In my case I prefer 'array solution' because it's simpler and don't need to know the name, only de value but it's a very valuable solution.